# Why is my question "opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions, deleted-questions

First timer in Stack Exchange, and I started with a deleted question. Here it is:

> I'm a newbie here. I'm pretty sure my question's already been asked, I tried to search for it but I could not find anything relevant, so sorry if it's the 1000th same question. So: Does it worth to study java and c++ together, are there any jobs where I'm going to have to use both? Or should I concentrate on solely one of them? Thx in advance.

I don't consider it as opinion-based, since I'm asking about facts, whether there are any jobs where both languages are used or not. Simple yes/no question.

Comment: Assuming you posted on Stack Overflow, you better ask on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) not here.

Comment: So what is better then? How do you choose when one person says *A* and the other says *B*? See [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Comment: I can't ask at Meta Stack Overflow, I need 5 reputation.

Comment: So get 5 reputation first it's really not that hard.

Comment: I don't want anyone to choose between java and c++, I just want to know, whether any jobs exist where both languages used together or not. Using the gorilla vs shark analogy: are there any places on Earth where gorillas and sharks live together?

Comment: Gorillas and sharks live together peacefully in many areas of the world.  Learn to learn, not to get a job.  The answer to your original question is a resounding *yes*; the answer to *this* question is because the idea of 'worth' is extremely subjective. You will get wildly varying answers depending on the answerer and the mood he or she is in.

Comment: @SeanAllred: Yeah, but that's just your opinion. ;)

Comment: @JonW Touché `;)` (Although to be clear to the OP, I think the question of whether or not the question is subjective is hardly subjective :).)

Comment: I'm getting to see your point why it's opinion-based, thx for all the responses! But I think gorillas and sharks don't live together anywhere, but we really should not start an argument about it...

Comment: @prologic: C++ and Java are not Shark and Gorilla here. The options are between *concentrate on one* and *concentrate on both*. You have two opposing choices there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> does it worth to study java and c++ together...?

Any answer would be entirely based on the opinion of the person answering.

That's what makes it opinion based.

> are there any jobs where I'm going to have to use both?

Possibly. Are you going to ever have such a job? No one can tell.

> Or should I concentrate on solely one of them?

Again - different people have different opinions on this.

Comment: Okay, I think I see your point, I'm gonna ask it in another forum. Maybe Stackexchange should have an "opinion-based" flag for these kind of questions.

Comment: @prologic - we do have it as a close reason. We also explain that this kind of question is not suitable on our sites (this is in the [help]).

Comment: Thx for the answer, maybe I'm gonna try to get my answer somewhere else.

Comment: @prologic We have chat for this type of thing precisely, though. Now, whether or not chat is *useful* on SO---I'm not sure. I can only speak for TeX.SX.